# Java Springboot, RestTemplate result number encoding

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, rfc

I've an api, which read from an OracleDB. If i call it directly it returns:

```
{
 ...
 ...
 numericField: 910010000346422907
 ...
 otherNumericField: 2018020800
 ...
}
```

but if i call it through a springboot java server using

```
URI targetUrl= UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
            .queryParams(queryParameters)
            .build()
            .encode()
            .toUri();

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, String.class);
```

values in result string looks like

```
numericFiled: 9.1001000034642291E17 .... otherNumericField: 2.0180208E9
```

The api returns Content-Type `application/json; charset=UTF-8`. How could I correctly read numeric value correctly?

Comment: Why you are converting Object to string?  It must be something like restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, YourObj.class);

Comment: I would like to parse json without know how it's made by before, i don't have any YourObj.class

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a POJO class with all the properties, something like this, you can use lombok to create `Getters` and `Setters` for you by annotations [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)

```
public class ResponseData {

      private double numericFiled

      private double otherNumericField

   // Getters and Setters

  }
```

And in the `getForObject` call just pass the `Class` type

```
ResponseData result = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, ResponseData.class);
```

If you don't know the JSON schema then use `Map<Object,Object> map`, but always recommended parsing to model and you can also ignore the fields that you don't need and don't know

Comment: What if i don't know before the object schema, but I'm sure to find those numeric fields?

Comment: check my updated comment in answer @tommasoballardini

Comment: can you show the JSON response and `ResponseData` @tommasoballardini